# How can I check the JTextField only contains upper and lower case letters and '-' using regex

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

How can I check the JTextField only contains upper and lower case letters and '-' using regex, and then add that to an ArrayList? I've looked all over the place and most places say the same kind of thing, but I can't figure out what I'm missing. Here's the snippet of code that's going wrong:

```
public static void AddArray(ArrayList arrayWords, JTextField textFieldEntry, JLabel labelWords){
    String textFieldValueRed = textFieldEntry.getText();

//Check that textfield only contains letters and '-'
    Pattern p= Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z-]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(textFieldEntry.toString());
    boolean b = m.matches();
    if (b==true){
        arrayWords.add(textFieldEntry.getText().toString());
        labelWords.setText("'"+textFieldEntry.getText()+"' was added to list.");
    }
    else{
        labelWords.setText("The string ‘"+textFieldEntry.getText()+"’ was not added to the list as it is not a valid word.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just ask for a solution, try it by yourself and you will probably learn something! I prefer this site, you could at least give it a try: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `+` for atleast one or more values

```
Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z-]+");
```

otherwise this `[a-zA-Z-]` will match as `true` if there is only single character mean

`[]` will match only single value defined inside it

and

`+` mean there will be one or more values so it matches 1 or more occurrences of the preceding token.

Update : the other issue is , you need use a `String` value i.e `textFieldValueRed` which you fetched using `getText()` function not `textFieldEntry.toString()` because this `textFieldEntry.toString()` will give a some unexpected value i.e class signature along with hashcode so follow this

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(textFieldEntry.getText());
```

complete code

```
public static void AddArray(ArrayList arrayWords, JTextField textFieldEntry, JLabel labelWords){

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z-]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(textFieldEntry.getText());
    if (m.matches()){
        arrayWords.add(textFieldEntry.getText());
        labelWords.setText("'"+textFieldEntry.getText()+"' was added to list.");
    }
    else{
        labelWords.setText("The string ‘"+textFieldEntry.getText()+"’ was not added to the list as it is not a valid word.");
    }
}
```

or you do this without creating any `Pattern` object

```
    if (textFieldEntry.getText().trim().matches("[a-zA-Z-]+")){
        arrayWords.add(textFieldEntry.getText());
        labelWords.setText("'"+textFieldEntry.getText()+"' was added to list.");
    }
    else{
        labelWords.setText("The string ‘"+textFieldEntry.getText()+"’ was not added to the list as it is not a valid word.");
    }
```

Comment: if you don't want the flag 'b' for later use  you can simply use `if(m.matches())`

Comment: I've made both your suggested changes but it's still returning the 'else' option when the user inputs 'lol'

Comment: @Eishknaar mention the input that you are using because these should be no problem with this regex as per your requirements mentioned in post plus update the current code that you are using

Comment: @Eishknaar read the updated answer , there was a logical mistake in code , rest the suggested pattern has no issue